# rviz UDP over unreliable network?

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there an option for rviz to subscribe to topics via UDP? On our diagnostics side, we have an unreliable connection but would love to get some info out.

Is there an alternative to writing an echo node that subscribes via UDP then relays it to a topic for rviz to open up?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45544/rviz-udp-over-unreliable-network?/) by [Eruditass](https://answers.ros.org/users/3250/eruditass/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2012-10-10

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Discovered that the ROS relay has the unreliable option built in, so at least we won't have to write our own relay.

---

Originally posted by [Eruditass](https://answers.ros.org/users/3250/eruditass/) with karma: 121 on 2012-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's currently no way to set ROS transport hints to UDP (unreliable) in the default RVIZ plugins without modifying the RVIZ source code. If you're interested in adding in this functionality, it might not be hard to check out the RVIZ source ( svn co https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/visualization/trunk/rviz ) and add these options.

You can find the "subscribe" calls and GUI config fields for the various default plugins in these files:
https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/visualization/trunk/rviz/src/rviz/default_plugin/

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2012-10-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4